# Let $\gcd(a,b)=1$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove $f:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $f(x,y)=ax+by$ is surjective.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

I don't really have an idea on how to prove this.

My thinking:

$f(x,y) = ax+by = \gcd(a,b) = 1$ by Bézout's identity.

To prove a function is surjective: Let $f(x,y)=m, m\in \mathbb{Z}$

Then prove $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z} $ such that $f(x,y) = ax+by=m$

Though I don't quite understand how $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is relevant to all of this. I've looked at other answers on this fourm but none make sense at all really. I know $ax+by=1$ has something to do with this but I don't quite know what. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Let $n\in\mathbb Z$. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$, so $f(xn,yn)=a(xn)+b(yn)=n$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, this proves that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I've looked at the answers but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696443/446262) completely answers your question.

Comment: @Joe I think I got it. So since $ax+by=1$ all you do is multiply both sides of the equation by any number in $\mathbb{Z}$, say $n$, and then your new $x = xn$ and your new $y = yn$.

Comment: @Yaya123: Yes. It perhaps help to use different variable names, in an effort to avoid a notational conflict: you want to show that $(\exists s)(\exists t)(as+bt=n)$. We know that $ax+by=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, and multiplying both sides by $n$ we get $a(xn)+b(yn)=n$. Therefore, we can set $s=xn$, $t=yn$.